# Default value and styling in text field in TCPDF

Tags: php, textfield, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a form in a PDF file with editable text fields that have a default value. Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P','mm','A5',true,'UTF-8',false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
$pdf->SetTitle('Document');

$pdf->SetMargins(0,0,0);
$pdf->setImageScale(1);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

$pdf->TextField('field',100,30,array(),array(V=>'hello world'),10,10);

$pdf->Output('out.pdf','I');
```

I'm testing this in Chrome's PDF viewer and Adobe Reader X and what happens is that the default text doesn't appear, although when I click the field it does. When I change the initial value and unfocus the field, the text field will be visible. If I don't change the initial field and just unfocus the field without changing anything, the text field will still not be visible.

Another problem is the ugly border that's around the field.

What I basically want to achieve is this:

```
<input type="text" value="hello world" style="border:0"/>
```

This is the generated PDF: [doc.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0j5gh0rt99ujbb4/doc.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

$pdf->TextField('field',100,30,array(),array(**'v'**=>'hello world'),10,10);

Answer (score 2):

See [TCPDF documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71d382a4356e7fb3f9fa72e53642c09c) and official [Javascript for Acrobat API reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) on a page 424

Or use

```
$pdf->TextField('customer', 159, 7, array('multiline'=>true, 'lineWidth'=>0, 'borderStyle'=>'none', 'defaultStyle' => array('textFont'=>array('fontWeight'=>'bold'))), array('v' => $customer_name));
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just started using TCPDF, and was having the same issue.

Change your Textfield to this

$pdf->TextField('field',100,30,array(),array('V'=>'hello world','dv'=>'hello world'),10,10);

you need both the 'v'=> setting AND the 'dv' => setting.

You can see the example of it in the example code example_014.php that's included with TCPDF

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we convert html to pdf (with lots of editable fields in it).
This code disabled borders for all fields in the converted pdf:

`$pdf->setFormDefaultProp(array('lineWidth' => 0, 'borderStyle' => 'none'));`